# Как добавить текст в поле с количеством товара?

Tags: html, jquery, css, wordpress

Всем привет! Есть поле с количеством товара. хочу сделать так, чтобы после цифры была еще надпись в поле. пр. 1 товар, 2 товара и т.д. Но, если ее просто добавить в value, то ничего показываться не будет. 
Подскажите плиз, как поступить? делаю по аналогии [с сайтом](http://velikorodnov.com/wordpress/flatastic/classic/?product=women-tops-blue-flowers)
Код привожу:

```html
<table class="description-table">
   <tbody>
   <tr>
    <td>Quantity:</td>
    <td class="product-quantity">
     <div class="quantity buttons_added"><input type="button" value="-" id="minus1" class="minus"><input type="number" step="1" min="1" max="5" name="quantity" value="1" title="Qty" class="input-text qty text" size="4"><input type="button" value="+" id="add1" class="plus"></div>    </td>
   </tr>
   </tbody>
  </table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Работающий пример ниже. Дальше стилями разукрасите, как вам нужно.

```js
$('#num_count').change(function(){
    var text_count = $('#text_count');
    var num = $(this).val() - 0;
    var text = 'товар';
    if (num > 1 && num < 5) text = text + 'а';
    else if (num >= 5) text = text + 'ов';
    text_count.text(text);
});

$('#button_minus, #button_plus').click(function(){
    var num_count = $('#num_count');
    var count = num_count.val() - 0;
    if ($(this).attr('id') == 'button_minus') count -= 1;
    else count += 1;
    if (count == 0) count = 1;
    num_count.val(count).trigger('change');
});
```

```css
#num_count { width:100px; }
#text_count { position:absolute; margin-left:-80px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="description-table">
   <tbody>
   <tr>
    <td>Quantity:</td>
    <td class="product-quantity">
                    <div class="quantity buttons_added"><input type="button" value="-" id="button_minus"><input type="number" step="1" min="1" max="5" id="num_count" name="quantity" value="1" title="Qty"><span id="text_count">товар</span><input type="button" value="+" id="button_plus"></div>    </td>
   </tr>
   </tbody>
  </table>
```

Comment: Супер! спасибо, только единственное стрелочки непонятно как номера прибавляют)

Comment: Они прибавляют согласно условию `step="1" min="1" max="5"` step - шаг, min - минимальное значение, max - максимальное значение

Comment: ок, благодарю Мышан)